# C# Change the displayed name of a column item

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui, boolean, inline

I have a kendo gridview where one of the columns is for a boolean value. In the column, the information comes up labeled either "true" (for 1 or true), "false" (for 0 or false), or blank (for null). This does not look very professional, and I am trying to change these values in the grid to instead be displayed as Yes, No, or None (respectively). The code I am using to try to make this happen is:

**Model:**

```
namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
    public class Companies
    {

        public string IsAdmitted { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Companies_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var companydata = new CompaniesDataContext())
        {
            List<Companies> model = new List<Companies>();
            var companylist = companydata.Companies_JBs.Select(s => s).ToList();
            foreach (var h in companylist)
            {
                Companies x = new Companies();
                x.IsAdmitted = h.IsAdmitted == (bool)true ? x.IsAdmitted = "Yes" : h.IsAdmitted == (bool)false ? x.IsAdmitted = "No" : x.IsAdmitted = "Null";
                model.Add(x);
            }

            return Json(companydata.Companies_JBs.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Company_Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.IsAdmitted).Title("Admitted:").Width(95);
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
         }
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add a Company"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Companies"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.ID))
        .Create(update => update.Action("Companies_Create", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Companies_Update", "Home"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Companies_Destroy", "Home"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Companies_Read", "Home"))
    )
)
```

When I put a breakpoint and check the value, it says that the IsAdmitted field items are labelled as Yes, No, or None (depending on their value in my sql database). However, in the grid itself they are still labeled true, false, or blank. Whats my problem here, Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are returning `Json(companydata.Companies_JBs.ToDataSourceResult(request));`?

You have to return `model`. So, the return statement of the controller method should be

```
return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```